# Is there an unofficial Box.com client for Linux?

Tags: file-sharing

I know Box.com does not have a non-server client for Linux. Is there, then, a way to download my files to my PC using an unofficial client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [box-linux-sync](https://github.com/noiselabs/box-linux-sync/tree/daemon) on github, but it's a command-line interface.

Comment: Thanks! Command line will work for me. I'm looking to move my Box files to Dropbox or Copy.

Comment: This no longer works now that their WebDAV is [broken and no longer supported](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8801023934995-WEBDAV-stopped-working)

Answer (score 3):

[rclone](https://rclone.org/) is a command line client which also supports [mounting](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) a remote box.com location.

`rclone mount ...` can mount any of Rclone’s cloud storage systems as a file system with FUSE, so it works without the expired WebDAV support.

**Limitations**

Without the use of “--vfs-cache-mode” this can only write files sequentially, it can only seek when reading. This means that many applications won’t work with their files on an rclone mount without “--vfs-cache-mode writes” or “--vfs-cache-mode full”. See the [File Caching section of the docs](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/#file-caching) for more info.

The bucket based remotes (eg Swift, S3, Google Compute Storage, B2, Hubic) do not support the concept of empty directories, so empty directories will have a tendency to disappear once they fall out of the directory cache.

It's available for download [here](https://rclone.org/downloads/)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! IMHO This answer could benefit from a bit more information. See if you agree? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-mount-box-com-cloud-storage-on-linux.html) explanation on how to mount box.com as a folder via webdav may also help.

Comment: WebDAV is not supported by Box.xom

Answer (score 1):

There also "[BOXFS](https://github.com/drotiro/boxfs2) - A FUSE-based filesystem for box.com" but I don't know if it is usable.

Answer (score 1):

WebDav will become depricated as of January 31, 2019.
https://community.box.com/t5/Box-Product-News/Deprecation-WebDAV-Support/ba-p/55684
As of this time there is no available client for Linux.